# python sum date + days

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a data frame with a column with number of dates since year 1900. I need to change the format to Y%m%d. For this I created a column datetime.date(1900,1,1) to which try to sum the number of days.

I am receiving this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and
>   'TimedeltaIndex'

This is my code:

```
df_vend['creation_date'] = np.where(df_vend['creation_date'] == 0,1,df_vend['creation_date'])
df_vend['base_date'] = [datetime.date(2019,1,1)] * len(df_vend.creation_date)
df_vend['creation_date'] = df_vend['base_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df_vend['creation_date'])
```

np.where is used to change dates with value 0.

Comment: Try replacing the second line with `df_vend['base_date']  = pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(2019,1,1))`

Comment: That worked. I had a couple of errors more, the final code is (of course the base date is 1900,1,1 not 2019,1,1: 
`df_vend['creation_date'] = np.where(df_vend['creation_date'] == 0,1,df_vend['creation_date'])
df_vend['base_date'] = [pd.to_datetime(datetime.date(1900,1,1))] * len(df_vend.creation_date)
df_vend['creation_date'] = df_vend['base_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df_vend['creation_date'],unit='days')`
Why is it necessary to use datetime.date, when I already used to_datetime?

Comment: You don't have to but you also do not need to multiply it by the length of the array as pandas will broadcast it for you. You can remove line 2 completely.  `df_vend['creation_date'] = pd.to_datetime('1/1/1900')  + pd.to_timedelta(df_vend['creation_date'])`